# Linking to a great answer rather than copy it?

Tags: discussion, answers, documentation

After I read the introduction about StackOverflow documentation, I instantly thought of one piece of documentation I wanted to see there. [This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866485/2003763), about how to `undo a Git commit`, that I referred to a lot during my first months of learning to use Git.

So how should I proceed? Should I link this answer into the documentation or should I copy the content? I see benefits and problems with both approaches but I think it's mostly a policy to be decided.

Comment: I'd say my concern is exactly the same, but about official documentation of things maintained typically by their authors.

Comment: But if you mean on their own websites @BartekBanachewicz there is still a point to copy it to avoid broken links. But of course still has the downside to duplicate the information, updates won't follow.

Comment: Exactly, it's the case of "bad" fragmentation that was mentioned in one of the earlier posts about the docs. Everything that is supposed to even remotely look like an official documentation will a) lag behind b) risk being outdated.

Comment: +1, I'm eager to hear the community's opinion on this. Would it be appropriate to leave a comment for the author recommending that they contribute their content to the documentation?

Comment: Same question also asked here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328444/2003763 but not answered because of multiple questions in the same thread.

Comment: +1 There should be a guideline for this. There's a lot of great answers that would benefit from being a documentation rather than an answer so others can contribute. Maybe link to the author, or the original question. Or maybe a button on answers letting the author know that this answers should be copied to documentation.