# Where to discuss how to organize documentation for a tag/topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I think SO documentation is very similar to Wikipedia. People will need a space to discuss issues to avoid edits going back and forth. Did SO think about what would be the suitable place to have these discussions?

For example, for the [git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git) there is a [committing topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/323/committing) that deals with how to commit using Git (`git commit` command). But I would also like to put there examples of how to remove a commit (see *[Linking to a great answer rather than copy it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328420/linking-to-a-great-answer-rather-than-copy-it)*). But that's a different command, namely `git reset` that is used in that case. Therefore I'm afraid that other people, whose documentation logic is closer to the Linux `man` pages, may not agree with putting some `git reset` instructions into the `Committing` topic.

What would be the place to talk with these people and explain them my vision?

Comment: I think it is very different to Wikipaedia - and infinitely superior.

Comment: @Chenmunka well I did not mean to compare SO and Wikipedia, I merely pointed one similarity: People who disagree need to discuss.

Comment: I don't know where the docs-beta questions went, but I did start a question where I asked for a Wikipedia "Talk page"-like discussion section per topic.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329173/

Comment: Wikipedia contains mostly correct articles, while Documentation so far contains mostly incorrect random stuff. So yeah it is quite different - it's poor man's Wikipedia, exactly as we predicted it would become.