# What is "You have already requested this type of improvement"?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I wanted to add an example to `sql` and as soon as I clicked `add an example` I was presented with a message stating no more examples could be created because there was already a max number of examples for sql.  As I browsed the sql examples for the topic `SELECT` it is literally full of jibberish and garbage examples.

I then saw someone did a hello world in sql, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/222/select/16592/hello-world-in-sql#t=201608151854058763783 so I thought this was pretty much garbage and I don't believe any outsider trying to learn sql would benefit from such an example.  I down voted it and flagged it as low quality but as soon as I do that I get this:

[image]

What does that mean that I have already requested this type of improvement?  This was my first time flagging it.  The sql examples for SELECT are not good at all and it sucks we cannot add more examples but I can understand the fact that we don't want too many of them.

Comment: Downvotes get converted into improvement requests if you pick a downvote reason. Sounds like we need to be more clear about that happening (and at least perhaps disable the "used" IR reasons in the flag dialog).

Comment: It sounds like you are using "topic" when you mean "example". As far as I know, there's no limit to the number of topics in a tag.

Comment: Sorry I meant example...this is all too confusing if you haven't noticed.  The UI is very difficult to navigate.

Comment: @AdamLear - But even if they do I shouldn't be presented with this message in red because my "request for clarification or improvements" is still taken and shown when I go to that page.  I don't think you need a message at all, simply swallow it.

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but: I'm not a fan of that "one improvement at a time" rule generally. If I want to suggest two things, I have to (a) write them into a single request, which someone might do partially and then dismiss; or (b) write only one of them, remembering the other to post later. I've had (a) happen with proposed topics, too. I'm hoping a better comment/discussion system comes along to supplant this.

Comment: @Frank - Speaking of the word comment - why can we not comment on an example?  We need that feature immediately!

Comment: @JonH Like I said, we need to improve how this is presented. Swallowing a message doesn't necessarily make sense since not every situation follows the pattern here, but we can definitely do better than what's happening right now.

Comment: @AdamLear - Understandable - what about comments on examples is that possible or has that been mentioned?

Comment: @JonH It's come up a couple times, IIRC. There's a feature request here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328895/why-are-there-no-comment-features-for-examples

Comment: @AdamLear - Thanks for the reference point, will upvote it!