# How can I discuss existing topics in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

We can easily discuss requested topics (by adding comments), but when a topic has been created we can only request for improvement.

But I have something to say or I'd like to ask something about the topic itself, and it is not directly related to flagging for moderator attention or any flagging at all. I wish I could **clarify something about the subject of the existing topic**, its purposes and define the aim of the topic **before asking for improvement** or suggesting any edits.

I reckon, **flagging** is inappropriate for that, because it **is a request for changes which, I am sure, have to be done**. I mean without understanding the target of the topic it is unlikely to be developed in right direction.

As far as there is no comments available for existing topic, is there any substitution (except flagging)?

What should I do?

---

There is also the button "Ask Question" at the bottom of the page. If its purpose is to ask questions about some documentation topics, how should we tag them properly?

Still, I think questions are a wrong place to discuss a particular topic, because they don't have any real value for programmers; they only might be useful for authors of the topic.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328895/why-are-there-no-comment-features-for-examples

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328422/where-to-discuss-how-to-organize-documentation-for-a-tag-topic

Comment: SO Meta is the place until another dedicated place will be created by SO.

Comment: @Trilarion, my question somehow must've confused you. I am not interested in asking general questions about features of Documentation, I am interested in asking quesiton about particular content of a particular topic inside Documentation

Comment: @NickRoz I don't think I'm confused. Ask it here or nowhere. There is no other place currently afaik.

Comment: Step 1:  [Get this implemented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329686/allow-for-area-51-like-mini-metas-per-documentation-tag). Step 2: Problem solved.

Comment: At first I thought I should close this question as a duplicate, but right now I think, let it be here for it propagates votes to the related ones. Some questions have better titles, others have better content. One way or another seekers will become informed

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I'm getting you correct, but as I understood the idea so far, there are 3 options how to treat this:

- If your question is about something that should be improved.... Well that's what the "Request Example Improvement" flags are intended for, also you can leave a comment as part of them.
- If it is a content flaw, it is perfectly valid to just improve it yourself. (In a perfect documentation world at least.)
- And in case it is a question about understanding the contents, there is no better way than asking on Stack Overflow's Q&A system about it.

I can't think of any way that might not be sorted in one of this 3 cases.

Comment: Well, have a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328895/why-are-there-no-comment-features-for-examples), my question might not be a duplicate, but actually has similar background

Comment: @NickRoz; Well I'd say that's one of the flaws of documentation in itself right now. how to handle it? should comments be related to the revision? So when ever some one changes anything, the comments should be cleared and some one had to repost them? Or should they be related to the example? So even after someone fixed the bad example, comments complain about bad practice, letting one assume the good way is considered bad practice? Both ways wouldn't solve the problem. And even if, after correcting the bad practice, who ever feels so, jsut could put it back in again.

Comment: how to tag the question about Documentation topic?

Comment: @NickRoz: If you want to know somethign about i.e. the freeing memory example on C pointers and have a specific question. Why it is required to tag it as documentation related? You can link to it. But I don't see why that tag would be required. Same as it wouldn't be related to tag a homework as such, jsut because your question is about homework.

Comment: Because my question would be not about programming, but about topic organisation instead. Do you ask questions about SO in SO? No, you ask them in meta. Where should I ask question about content of topic, about ways to improve it?

Comment: @NickRoz: If it is a methodical question on meta aswell. In case it is about some thing related to a specific example. taking the steps of improving it or requesting to improve it. thats simply the way I udnerstood it beeing expected to work. I might be wrong. for that case treat my answer acordingly. But again: I don't see so far a problem in where to place such comments. I more so just see a problem in how to treat such comments in an usefull way, and thats sadly right now quite another dilemma.

Comment: @NickRoz: After I see your comment is getting so many upvotes I have to ask it again, since maybe I'm missunderstanding it. But isn't exactly that the point for improvement request flags?(note, not moderator atention flags!) I would the case you have mentioned flaging as low quality and afterwards explain why it is bad organized or at least why you think it is, and then elaborate in the comment how to improve it. Why isn't it fitting for your case?

Comment: I do not treat all the topics as if they are poor quality (because they are quite good in fact), whereas flagging tells so. I just want to clarify their purpose just like when I am doing while elaborating proposal. And I don't want to move examples or suggest any edits immediately, because I am not the only expert. Quite often, when a person thinks his or her improvements are the best others disagree. As a result they spawn a bunch of different edits which become rejected. I'd rather consult others and in case people agree I would make an edit or flag the question afterwards if needed

Comment: @NickRoz: But thats actually the way I observed and expected the improvement system to be for, or at least to be expected to be for. Isn't that the case? I mean actually the use cases of the flags are not fitting that much. But after all shouldn't this be the way to do it?

Comment: perhaps, you are right, but as you can see, according to amount of upvotes, current solution does not fulfil needs 100%. Either flagging should be improved or something else (comments feature, e.g.) added.

Comment: @NickRoz: I'm not saying it is actually fulfilling its purpose. But since you didn't tag this as feature request but as discussion and support, I just told you how it is actually intended to work.