# Is it OK to copy some of my own Q&A content over to Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I once wrote a question and an answer about how to avoid problems when using Qt signals and slots. My hope was to help people with that technique and to reduce redundant questions:

[My signal / slot connection does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422154/my-signal-slot-connection-does-not-work/26422155#26422155)

Now Documentation has been introduced. It appears to me that my question and answer maybe could fit better into Documentation.

Is it desired that such Q&A are moved or copied or referenced or integrated in some way into documentation?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328687/, [Linking to a great answer rather than copy it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328420)

Comment: Relevant info from chat:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31872715#31872715

Comment: I think it's ok to take a good general answer of yours, and use it as a starting point for an example on Docs.  Rework it so that it is as general as possible.  Remove any text or code that was specific to the question.  Add important general info that may have been missing from the more specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing *inherently* wrong with reusing your own Q&A content in Documentation.

Of course, Documentation needs to truly benefit from it. It has to be a perfect fit for where you intend to add it - a rule that applies to both content you write afresh, and content you have already written elsewhere.

Attribution of the original Q&A post is [not required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89377) when re-publishing your own content because the content is yours, and you simply re-publish it.*

If you want to feel less like a cheapskate, take your original Q&A contribution as a basis, and start improving and editing it into a magnificent example of Documentation that will echo through the ages. (Or at least, through the next two years.)

There's always detail you can add, sentences that can be more focused, and so on.

<sub>* = I am not a lawyer. But I'm  confident this is how it works. (If an actual lawyer with knowledge in U.S. copyright law could chime in, please do!) In this context, no one is going to care either way though.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

I think that's OK, as long as you don't break the [our license](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Quotation from the link above:

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this
> content, we **require** that you:
>
> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn't have to be obnoxious;
>    a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Actually, I think it's OK even to copy **others** Q&A content over to Documentation according to our license.

Comment: This doesn't apply to your *own* content, though, which the question is about.

Comment: @Pekka웃 IMHO If it's OK to copy other's content, it's also OK to copy oneself's content. Anyway, in both cases, contributions belong to the SO community, and are thus under the same license.

Comment: `Anyway, in both cases, contributions belong to the SO community, and are thus under the same license` Nope. Your own content always belongs to you. You have granted the community a perpetual license to use your content, but you have not given it property rights. By copying your content over to Documentation, you *re-publish* it - that doesn't require attribution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89377