# Where should canonical examples live?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In the past I've written what I think are some canonical examples -- or very close to canonical examples --in answers to questions in my area of expertise on SO. Now there is Documentation, which seems to be the place to put canonical examples.

So now I'm left with the question of what to do with these examples. Should I copy them from SO to Documentation? If so, should I remove them from SO and link to the example on Documentation? If I improve the example for Documentation, should I "backport" the changes to the original SO question?

Similarly, when I see a new question for which I want to provide a really good example, should the pattern be to add it to Documentation first and then link to it in the SO answer, or add it to Documentation and SO at the same time? Or answer the question on SO and not add anything to Documentation?

Comment: And also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329126/is-it-ok-to-copy-some-of-my-own-qa-content-over-to-documentation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

For existing answers, you should leave them where they are so existing links remain valid.  Editing the answer to just link to Docs would create a link-only answer -- and given how easy it is to edit Docs content, it's likely the link will point to something you didn't intend.  (I don't know how to link directly to a specific revision.)

Comment: I definitely don't plan to remove existing answers. The question is more about whether the code example in the answer should be moved to Documentation or not. I agree that link-only answers are bad, even when the link points to Documentation. But it's also arguably bad to have the same example in two places.

Comment: There will be no broken links with Documentation, as said in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation). If something is deleted, there should be a link to a version when the content existed.

Comment: @Laurel Sure, but what if the content was _edited_, not deleted?  I expect it to show the most recent revision, not the one from when the link was created.  I'm not confident that the editing/approval flow won't result in dramatic changes to topics/examples; indeed, such changes may be necessary to improve them.  (If you actually do link to a specific revision, then it's merely annoying, but given how often people get this wrong when citing Wikipedia I'm not confident answerers will do it if it isn't the default behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally think editing so it links to is a bad idea as you will just end up with disjointed porting of information which will only seek to confuse people.